# Capture image through Canon camera using Java on Linux OS

Tags: java

I want to create a Java program that will access the camera and display the images to be shot on computer screen.
Java program will handle the camera for image capture or recording video.

Is there any free API available for this purpose that supports Linux OS as well?
I want to use Canon T3 DSLR camera.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Canon Hack Development Kit](http://chdk.wikia.com)

I didn't notice your Canon T3 (maybe in dev) but you'll find useful info with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the link you posted describe about loading some kind of program on the SD card of camera.
But I want to use camera with the help of APIs only.

Comment: @VikasKumar You can create scripts but I don't know if they can live outside the camera.